# How to say in english something like this

Tags: american-english, phrases, sentence-usage

When you talk about conditions, for example:

> I would rather have done something than .....

and someone tells you:

> *You don't need to make such a choice.* (you already are in a good position, so why are you saying this?)

I don't know how to properly say it in English but I'll try to compose a sentence this way:

> You don't need to put yourself in front of such a choice.

How to say this properly in American English?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are two ways which come to my mind.

> You do not need to put yourself in this situation.

or

> You should not care to do such choice.